# Disable "Generate new password and notify user immediately" checkbox while creating User via API

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, apexrest

I have a usecase where I am creating new users via REST API. When we create a new user from UI then there is this checkbox `Generate new password and notify user immediately` which is selected by default. Is there any way to set it to false when creating the user via API. I don't want the email notification to be sent on user creation.
Is there any boolean flag which I can set to false when creating user or something like that?

Comment: I dont think there is any email being sent when we create user via API. You can just create user, but finally you will have to go to User UI and click `Generate new password and notify user immediately` if required.

Comment: Is email notification triggering, when you create a user via rest api?

Comment: If you create Users through API there will be no emails being sent from Salesforce.

Comment: And what abt the time when updating user details via API? Let's say I update the email address of the user programmatically, will it send email or not in that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable 'Generate new password and notify user immediately' via API, check [limitation](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdXLHUA3/user-field-api-generate-new-password-and-notify-user-immediately).  Default value of checkbox field is set to [true](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZggUAF/default-false-for-field-generate-new-password-and-notify-user-immediately) and you would receive notification when there are any updates.

As a workaround, Use Data loader since the checkbox(Generate new password and notify user immediately) is not available and password is not generated. You are able to select the desired users from a user list view and reset the password for all users.  More details [here](https://meighanrockssf.com/projects/mass-create-users/).

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question myself. If we create the new user via rest API then, the newly created user don't receive any email regarding the password.